# calculate root mean square, ratio of power, constant false alarm, ... of a signal

Tags: fft, matlab, discrete-signals, signal-detection, analytic-signal

I am new to Digital Signal Processing, and am reading a paper. I don't know how they can extract some features from signal, like root mean square (RMS), Constant False Alarm Rate - CFAR, Mean Value Dispersion Statistic – MVD, Ratio of Power – ROP, and Autocorrelation from a signal, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Could anyone please help explain to me how, and, if it is possible, could you please show me some code to get them?

I've tried to write some codes to calculate these parameters. Could you please take a look:

***RMS***:

```
for i= 1:floor(time(end)/tPeriod)  
    tBegin = (i-1)*tPeriod;  
    tEnd = i*tPeriod;  
    index = find((time>=tBegin)&(time<tEnd));  
    RMS(i) = sqrt(mean(data(index).^2));    %equation 1  
    tPlot = [tPlot tEnd];  
end
```

***CFRA***:

```
for i= 1:floor(time(end)/tPeriod)  
    tBegin = (i-1)*tPeriod;  
    tEnd = i*tPeriod;  
    indexTime = find((time>=tBegin)&(time<tEnd));  
    y = fft(data(indexTime),M)/M;   % M is the number of fft points  
    y = 2*abs(y);  
    df = fMax/M;  
    f = [0:M-1]*df;  
    indexF = find((f>=n1)&(f<n2));  
    CFAR(i) = sum(y(1:M/2)).^v;  
    tPlot = [tPlot tEnd];  
end
```

***ROP***:

```
for i= 1:floor(time(end)/tPeriod)  
    tBegin = (i-1)*tPeriod;  
    tEnd = i*tPeriod;  
    indexTime = find((time>=tBegin)&(time<tEnd));  
    y = fft(data(indexTime),M)/M;  
    y = 2*abs(y);  
    df = fMax/M;  
    f = [0:M-1]*df;  
    indexF = find((f>=n1)&(f<n2));  
    ROP(i) = sum(y(indexF).^2)/sum(y.^2);  
   tPlot = [tPlot tEnd];  
end
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its present form. There just isn't enough information given about the system (or the signal)

Comment: @user1624637 Is this the paper you're reading? http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1678-58782006000100014

Comment: @ Dilip: the input signal is raw acoustic signal. Is there any missing information? I'm so sorry but I'm new to DSP therefore I want to know how those features were calculated. The paper I'm reading is like the link from Datageist

Comment: @ Datageist: you are defenitely right. I'm reading that paper but I don't understand. Could you please help me?

Comment: Acoustic signal in my case was assumed that it is essentially non-stationary.

Comment: @user1624637 but the equations are given on the page that is linked to. What's the question?